# How to read specific lines in a file in BASH?

Tags: bash

`while read -r line` will run through each line in a file. How can I have it run through specific lines in a file, for example, lines "1-20", then "30-100"?

Answer (score 5):

One option would be to use `sed` to get the desired lines:

```
while read -r line; do
  echo "$line"
done < <(sed -n '1,20p; 30,100p' inputfile)
```

Saying so would feed lines 1-20, 30-100 from the `inputfile` to `read`.

Answer (score 3):

@devnull's sed command does the job. Another alternative is using awk since it avoids doing the read and you can do the processing in awk itself:

```
awk '(NR>=1 && NR<=20) || (NR>=30 && NR<=100) {print "processing $0"}' file
```

Comment: what is the awk syntax for a) printing specific lines (e.g.: lines 43 and 51) or lines provided in some sort of list (e.g.: line numbers from [3,77,93,22]?